# Как указать ник, данные отправителя рассылки в боте aiogram, следующим сообщением

Tags: python, aiogram, рассылка

```
    @dp.callback_query_handler(text='next', state=bot_mailing.state)
    async def start(call: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
users = await commands.select_all_users()
data = await state.get_data()
text = data.get('text')
await state.finish()
for user in users:
    try:
        await dp.bot.send_message(chat_id=user.user_id, text=text)
        await sleep(0.5)
    except Exception:
        pass
await call.message.answer('Рассылка выполнена')
```

Comment: Создал рассылку в боте,, хочу привязать к сообщению, либо следующим сообщением, данные отправителя данной рассылки. Как это реализовать в данном коде?

Comment: Таким образом :    f'Запрос сделал:\n'
                         f'Имя - {user.first_name}\n'
                         f'Фамилия - {user.last_name}\n'
                         f'Ник - @{user.username}\n'